# Is createTextNode completely safe from HTML injection & XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, security, web, xss

I'm working on a single page webapp. I'm doing the rendering by directly creating DOM nodes. In particular, all user-supplied data is added to the page by creating text nodes with `document.createTextNode("user data")`.

Does this approach avoid any possibility of HTML injection, cross site scripting (XSS), and all the other evil things users could do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It creates a plain text node, so yes, as far as it goes.

It is possible to create an XSS problem by using an unsafe method to get the data from whatever channel it is being input into to `createTextNode` though.

e.g. The following would be **unsafe**:

```
document.createTextNode('<?php echo $_GET['xss']; ?>');
```

… but the danger is from the PHP `echo`, not the JavaScript `createTextNode`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP. Is that example allowing the user to request data from elsewhere and have it inserted as text on the page?

Comment: @breischl — The PHP takes input from the query string of the URL (which is external data) and drops it into the output without escaping.

Comment: But it would still be output as plain text, no matter what was in it, right? So you couldn't make the browser do anything, aside from displaying some text?

Comment: PHP builds the text of the page before it is sent to the client.  An attacker could provide a value like `'); alert('you just got xssed!` to the PHP script, which would then build a malfunctioning script on the page, and the client would run it, not knowing that the script had been altered before it left the server.  If you're not using a server-side language, this is not an issue.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks for the clarification. In my particular case, all the data is sent to the client as JSON objects and then rendered out, so I don't think that's an issue. But that's a good example to keep in mind.

Comment: @Quentin, I'm having the same question, so from your response, it is safe to use createTextNode() when working with JS, because I assume that it takes whatever input, store it as txt, and the Browser display it without interpret it. is that correct ??

Comment: I don't get the example. Wouldn't document.createTextNode() be running client/browser side, and php be running server side, and therefore this is a none-issue? I guess you could run JavaScript server side, build up the DOM, then output it all to a file, and run the contents of the file thereby executing any PHP code inside it, but I don't imagine that is how server side JS normally works...

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 Check the comment by@apsillers: the `$_GET['xss']` has JS in it that closes the `createTextNode` function call and then has some extra JS to run.

But it's true that in the PHP case it's the back-end that is vulnerable to XSS by allowing you to insert arbitrary JS, and the fact that this is done alongside `createTextNode` is irrelevant.

Comment: The example still makes no sense to me. Why is PHP code inside a JavaScript string? The PHP code would not get executed, it would just appear in the text node.

Comment: Since the code in the example is JavaScript, not PHP, none of that PHP code would get run or expanded or processed as PHP code any way. It's just a JavaScript string exactly as you see it in the example.

Comment: This answer is dangerous and contradicts itself. I'm going to edit it and remove most of the answer unless you can defend the answer. Saying it both avoids these problems and is vulnerable to them is the contradiction. The example of a vulnerability makes no sense and is irrelevant as it is just some PHP code inside a JavaScript string.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 late reply sorry. The PHP example is there to show the case where PHP generates the JavaScript in the back-end and only then will the JS snippet be sent to the front-end. But this just adds confusion with regarding to the original question as it demonstrates how a *PHP back-end* can be vulnerable to XSS, but makes it seem that `createTextNode` is somehow to blame, too.

Comment: Wouldn't that PHP code never run though because it's just a JavaScript string?

Comment: Nevermind, I get it now.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's XSS safe, as would be using `someElement.innerText = "..."`.

<sup>(The sibling answer adds confusion by including the XSS-vulnerable PHP snippet.)</sup>