# Can these javascript methods be considered XSS safe?

Tags: javascript, html, xss, single-page-application

I am implementing a so called "single page app" which accepts JSON as input. That also means that all HTML is rendered in the browser, also all templates (am using knockout) are seemingly unaffected by user input, in the sense that the template is not constructed dynamically by the backend but rather embedded statically in the client. In other words, I do NOT anything like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="$var">'
```

So all rendering of user content essentially boils down to these JS methods:

```
document.createTextNode(userVar); // for displaying static text
inputElement.value = userVar; // for populating input fields
document.title = userVar; // some user input can be reflected in the doc title
window.history.pushState = ... // no user input is set here directly, but there are URIs where this could be set using an outside link
```

So now the question would be: are these methods all *100% XSS safe?* Or would there still be any way to trigger a XSS attack - and if "yes", how could this be done?

Comment: We cannot possibly tell you based on so little information. Are you rendering a users *own content* back to them, or are you rendering content from one user to a different user?

Comment: "which accepts JSON as input" json from where?

Comment: Well just ask what you need to know, I thought the information should be enough. Well, in most cases (but not all) the user input is rendered back to him, but there might be cases where an admin can look at other users data. But how is this relevant here at all? The question was if its possible to trigger such an attack by using these four JS methods and any content placed in "userVar"

Comment: JSON input comes from the backend (by using a REST API), but how is this relevant? Just imagine **any** string content be possible in "userVar".

Comment: @Jamiec, I think I must disagree here. Again the question is: "is it possible to trigger a XSS attack using **these four methods** and **any** content placed in "userVar". If "yes", please tell me exactly how this could work. If "no", I consider my App safe, since only these methods are effectively used to render the content. And AFAIK these are all not usable to mount5 such an attack. Of course I am well aware that its possible by using "innerHTML" for example, but this was not the actual question.

Comment: Did you mean [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) or [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)?

Comment: jamie I mean as I said ;) So the whole sequence would be like this: var tag = document.createElement("span"); tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userVar)); rootEle.appendChild(tag);

Comment: Uhhm, "pedantic dickweed", really? I mean I have given an exact question, and you gave me an answer that was  simply not related to this question. But since this question is security related, I assume that "pedantic dickweed" is a compliment. Imho this topic deserves to be pedantic, since I absolutely want to make sure there is no hole here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe those four functions are safe. The `document.createTextElement` method [appears to be safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654555/is-createtextnode-completely-safe-from-html-injection-xss), and none of the other methods are capable of adding objects to the DOM.

In order to launch an XSS attack, an attacker must be able to either hijack an existing script to run arbitrary code (why eval is evil) or insert their own scripts through vectors such as `<script>` tags. Since you are using methods that aren't capable of adding elements to the DOM, nor are they capable of manipulating event handlers, I would think that you are safe.

We would also need to be able to see more of your backend code to make that call, however, but on the frontend it looks okay.

Comment: It is also not possible for an attacker to take over my script, at least I am not aware how this could be done. The JS is completely static, and I do not use "eval"

Comment: JS is not static, it's dynamic and runs in the browser environment, hence why you can create event listeners, timers, etc. It can be modified very easily via the Chrome Inspector. Whilst the file itself won't be updated, the code within can be altered (for the session, i.e. before page refresh) to allow for an attack.

Comment: on top of all the answers above you might find this link useful: http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/

Comment: @diggersworld, that's called self-XSS and no site is safe from that. Clearly people can inject arbitrary code in their own browser, it's only dangerous if an attacker can run code on **other people's browsers**

Comment: @howderek yes I know, hence I say that it is pointless in my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not your JavaScript is susceptible to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) is one question, whether it is secure at all is another. The idea with XSS is that the attacker puts code into your system, which is then run by another user, it might redirect them to another (potentially malicious) site for example.

If you're not storing the input data to your system, and then displaying it to another user, then you're safe from XSS. The user can only attack themselves, which is pointless in my opinion.

If however you are storing the input data to your system, then you have a potential problem (hard to know without knowledge of your back-end). But whatever you submit via JavaScript, wherever you send it, the back-end has to process (verify and validate) it before storing to ensure it's not malicious.

Bottom line is don't rely on JavaScript. Whether your script is 10 lines, or 1,000,000 lines it can all be manipulated via the front-end because it runs client side. You can try this yourself in Google Chrome using the inspector.

Comment: Of course I know that the backend has to validate the stuff, so yes I do not rely solely on JS. But still it would be nice to know that the client is completely immune ** in addition**, and I am under the impression that this is the case using the methods I mentioned.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is: does my code take input from one user and show it to other users? If the answer is yes, then there is potential for XSS.

Comment: The answer is "yes", but where exactly is the "potential"?

Comment: The incoming JSON data you use to populate the page is the potential.

Comment: diggersworld, "potential" maybe but that does not mean there is a **concrete attack vector** that can be used. My goal is to harden the client to a point where it is simply technically impossible to launch such an attack. Therefore my question.

Comment: For example, if you have a `username` field on a registration form and the user enters `<script>SOME BAD ACTION HERE</script>` as a fake username, and you have a separate page that lists all your `usernames` (like, "who's online now?"), you have the potential to trigger the BAD ACTION on anyone that opens such page -- since the rogue username could result on a script being executed.

Comment: Well, if I set this text using createTextElement, and **not** via innerHTML, simply the string "<script>SOME BAD ACTION HERE</script>" is displayed. So what? I already tried that, since I am even populating text in a separate <span> in my GUI as soon as the user enters data in an input field. Nothing bad happens then.

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant "createTextNode" not "createTextElement"

Comment: If `<script>SOME BAD ACTION HERE</script>` is stored as is on a database and you create it dynamically on a SPA using `createTextNode`, it should be rendered as text (escaped `&lt;script&gt;SOME BAD ACTION HERE&lt;/script&gt;`, but readable for the end user) without problems. I personally would not do that and would keep the server validation/sanitizing -- you never know what your front end will be in the future.

Comment: (cont) But in such case, your SPA would receive a sanitized `&lt;script&gt;SOME BAD ACTION HERE&lt;/script&gt;` and `createTextNode` would escape it again to `&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;SOME BAD ACTION HERE&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;`. But essentially you are correct: your SPA is safe -- as long as you never change this without a lot of thought.

Comment: (yeat another comment) -- In essence, what you are doing is inverting the rule "never trust data from the client" to "never trust data from the server" :-)