How do I write this code without using .innerHTML?
I am writing a JavaScript code where some characters of the string have a color and I want to display them through the HTML elements. I only want the 'abc' to be blue and no color change with 'def'.
For example, if there's a variable:
word = '<span style="color: blue">abc</span>def'

I used this to display the text in the HTML element:
presentCell.innerHTML = word;

Is there a way to not use .innerHTML and do the same thing? I'm worried about security problems because I am getting user input for 'abc' and 'def'.
I am making this word variable with this function:


function changeTextColorArr (textArr, colorArr){
    resultArr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++)
    {
        color = colorArr[i] === "" ? "black" : colorArr[i];
        beginTag =   `<span style="color: ${color}">`
        endTag= '</span>';

        result = beginTag + textArr[i] + endTag;
        resultArr.push(result);
    }
    return resultArr;
}
//I get an array of an text and an array of colors correspoding to each text

let word = changeTextColorArr(["abc"], ["blue"]) + "def"; 
console.log(word)



#UPDATE 2


function changeTextColorArr(textArr, colorArr) {
  resultArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      const color = colorArr[i] === "" ? "black" : colorArr[i];

      span.style.color = color;
      span.textContent = textArr[i]; // Safely set the text content

      // push HTML code in a string format
      console.log( span.outerHTML);
      resultArr.push(span.outerHTML);
  }

  return resultArr;
}




document.createElement plus textContent

@DanielRobinson huh?

@mplungjan you're right. Thanks for the correction. I'll remove my comment

Avoid Using .innerHTML: Instead, create and append individual elements (e.g., ) directly to the DOM.
Use document.createTextNode: This ensures that text content is inserted safely without any unintended HTML rendering.
Use document.createElement: Create HTML elements like  programmatically.
function changeTextColorArr(textArr, colorArr) {
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); // Create a document fragment to avoid multiple reflows

for (let i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    const color = colorArr[i] === "" ? "black" : colorArr[i];

    span.style.color = color;
    span.textContent = textArr[i]; // Safely set the text content

    fragment.appendChild(span); // Append the span to the document fragment
}

return fragment;}


Thank you for the code example!
I made few edits to fit my program
Would this code be more safe than before?

The code is on the original post at #update2. Would it be safe because it inserts the text into a variable by "textContent" and then get the html code by .outerhtml?

You could do something like
presentCell.innerHTML = '';
presentCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word));


Is "createTextNode(word)" more safer then innerhtml? What's the difference?

Yes it is safe, read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654555/is-createtextnode-completely-safe-from-html-injection-xss#:~:text=Yes%2C%20it's%20XSS%20safe%2C%20as%20would%20be%20using%20someElement.
